# java - comparing numbers of different type, semantically

Tags: java, numbers, comparison, comparator, comparable

Say I have three numbers:

```
Comparable n1 = new Integer(432);
Comparable n2 = new Long(40);
Comparable n3 = new Double(500.12);
```

I would like to compare these numbers through the `Comparable` interface. However, this results in a `ClassCastException`.

```
n1.compareTo(n2);
```

Is there a way (utility function, external library, ...) to compare numbers of different type? In the example above, the number `n2` is smaller than `n1`, and `n1` is smaller than `n3`, semantically.

In the code, I have no knowledge about the concrete type of the numbers. Hence, I rely on the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: You may be able to cast them all down to the same type (double in this case) and work from there. Other than that, I don't think there is a standard interface that works for you. Comparable isn't the right choice I think

Comment: Yes, that works. I am looking for a function or library which does that for me. I rather re-use than implement myself. I suppose I am not the first.

Comment: I assume that you think you may have number classes that may implement Comparable, but not be able to use the normal comparison operators (i.e. < >)?  BigDecimal, for instance.  Otherwise - if you're restricted to int, float, double, long - I'd just use the less than greater than operators e.g. `int b = n3 > n2 ? 1 : (n3 < n2 ? -1 : 0);` will give the same result as you want from  n3.compareTo(n2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922790/838992) is exactly right on why you get the ClassCastException - the Comparable interface is generic and can only be used on objects of the same concrete type.

There may be other ways to solve your problem:

### Primitives and their object wrappers

If you are sure that all your numbers are primitives (`int, long, float, double`) or Objects for the classes that represent primitives (`Integer, Long, Float, Double`), then you can just use normal comparison operators e.g. for equivalence to `n1.compareTo(n2);`

```
int b = n1 > n2 ? 1 : (n1 < n2 ? -1 : 0);
```

### Subclasses of `Number`

If you are sure that all your variables are of a Class that extends `Number` i.e. `AtomicInteger, AtomicLong, BigDecimal, BigInteger, Byte, Double, Float, Integer, Long, Short`, you can use the following:

```
    private int compareNumbers(Number n1, Number n2)
    {
        Double n2c = n2.doubleValue();
        Double n1c = n1.doubleValue();

        return n1c.compareTo(n2c);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Integer n1 = new Integer(432);
        Long n2 = new Long(40);
        Double n3 = new Double(500.12);

        System.out.println(compareNumbers(n1,n2));
    }
```

***EDIT***

In response to comment discussion with OP - we noted that using `Double` as the base class for the `Number` comparison might give spurious equality if comparing two `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` numbers that are beyond the range of `Double` (therefore `.doubleValue()` returns `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` as appropriate)

If this is a concern, `compareNumbers()` could be altered as follows:

```
    private int compareNumbers(Number n1, Number n2)
    {
        BigDecimal n2c = new BigDecimal(n2.toString());
        BigDecimal n1c = new BigDecimal(n1.toString());

        return n1c.compareTo(n2c);
    }
```

***/EDIT***

### Implement `Comparable` but don't extend `Number`

If you can't even be sure that your variables extend Number, and you may be processing a variable with a class that represents a number, implements Comparable, but does not extend Number, I believe you can only compare the arguments if they are of the same class.  In this case, this should work, but I can't really imagine the use case:

```
    Comparable n1 = new WierdNonNumberExtendingInteger(432);
    Comparable n2 = new WierdNonNumberExtendingLong(40);
    Comparable n3 = new WierdNonNumberExtendingDouble(500.12);

    Integer b =  null;
    if (n1.getClass().isInstance(n2))
    {
       b =  n1.compareTo(n2);
    }
    else
    {
       System.err.println("Can't compare apples and oranges");
       System.err.print("You tried to compare " + n1.getClass().getSimpleName());
       System.err.print(" with " + n2.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive feedback. In your second option, you cast all primitive numbers to a `double` because a `double` has enough space to represent all primitive types? Is that statement always correct?

Comment: In my case, all numbers will be indeed a subclass of `Number`. But I don't know in advance if a certain number will be represented by an `int` or a `long` or a `float` or a ... It also might be a `BigInteger` or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: The first statement is correct, all primitives can be represented (albeit not with perfect precision) in the double space. As `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` extend Number, they must also return something in `.doubleValue()`, so option 2 doesn't apply only to primitives.  I have to admit - I'm not sure exactly how `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` behave if they represent a value of magnitude greater than `Double.MAX_VALUE`.  They're mandated to implement `.doubleValue()`, so a check of their API doc / specification should clarify.

Comment: I will have to check that out. I think the results will be undefined if a `BigInteger` of `BigDecimal` holds a value larger than `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Sorry for serial comment - just checked.  If the big numbers' magnitude is too big, they return Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY or Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY as appropriate. In that case, it's doesn't give undefined, but it does give spurious equality.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.  Of course - you could always use BigDecimal as your base class for comparison...

Comment: Using `BigDecimal` as a base class makes sense! I will implements it like this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare them that way. Comparable is a generic interface it accepts only the same type.

You can use a conversion method:

```
Comparable<Double> n1 = convertNumber(new Integer(432));
Comparable<Double> n2 = convertNumber(new Long(40));
Comparable<Double> n3 = convertNumber(new Double(500.12));

System.out.println(n1.compareTo(n2));

...

public Double convertNumber(Object o) {
    if(o instanceof Double) {
        return (Double)o;
    } else if(o instanceof Long) {
        return ((Long)o).doubleValue();
    } else if(o instanceof Integer) {
        return ((Integer)o).doubleValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned, you can't compare them "as-is", but you can implement a new comparator that will receive the different possible values and will know how to deal with them. Below is a possible implementation, where you have different constructors (per possible values - probably can improve that part) which convert the given value into a "base" type (double, in my case) - and the compareTo method can handle all types supported by the different constructors.

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        MyComparator n1 = new MyComparator(new Integer(432));
        MyComparator n2 = new MyComparator(new Long(40));
        MyComparator n3 = new MyComparator(new Double(500.12));
    }

static class MyComparator implements Comparable
{
    double baseVal = 0.0d;

    public double getValue() {
        return baseVal;
    }

    public MyComparator(double d) {
        this.baseVal = d;
    }

    public MyComparator(Long l) {
        this.baseVal = l.doubleValue();
    }

    public MyComparator(int i) {
        this.baseVal = (double)i;
    }

    public int compareTo(MyComparator toCompare) {
        return ((Double)this.getValue()).compareTo(toCompare.getValue());
    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        // implemented only to support required interface methods
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I will have to check that out. I think the results will be undefined if a `BigInteger` of `BigDecimal` holds a value larger than `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You Could always call intValue() method on Subclasses of Number (Integer,Float,...) and that's the a way to compare different types :

```
        Long l = Long.valueOf(432L);
        Double d = Double.valueOf(500.12D);
        Integer i = Integer.valueOf(432);

        Comparable lc = l.intValue();
        Comparable dc = d.intValue();
        Comparable ic = i.intValue();
        System.out.println(lc.compareTo(dc));
        System.out.println(dc.compareTo(ic));
        System.out.println(ic.compareTo(lc));
```